# how to correctly execute ./filename in terminal with nodejs

Tags: node.js, terminal

I'm trying to write a simple 1a2b game with nodejs I finished the program and could correctly run but when i use `chmod +x` to execute `./filename` command I get this error:

```
./1a2b.js: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./1a2b.js: line 1: `var readline = require('readline');'
```

this is a part of my code:

```js
var readline = require('readline'); // Line 1
var rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout); 
var num = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
var answer = '';
var a = 0;
var b = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){ // create random number 
  let select = getRandom(0,9-i)
  answer += num[select]
  num.splice(select, 1)
};
```

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [`Shebang`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line at the top of your file:

```
#!/usr/bin/node
```

Or run the file as

```
node ./1a2b.js
```